# append is slower with integer than string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I come across this code while looking for a way to measure functions speed.

```
def test():
    """Stupid test function"""
    L = []
    for i in range(100):
        L.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     import timeit
     print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

when I run it, it takes about 10 seconds, which is very strange for me. I recall that when I am appending 100.000 string into a string, it only takes 0.06 seconds. why does appending 100 integers into a list take 10 seconds? here are the code that I use to append stringt to list.

```
def wordlist1():
    fin = open("words.txt")
    word_list = []
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        word_list.append(word)
    return word_list
```

Comment: You are also using `range()` for your integers, which might be slower than `for line in fin`

Comment: Based on your title you should be comparing `test` with another function the same apart rom `L.append('a')`- you're comparing 2 completely different things

Comment: @Flob `range` in Python 3 doesn't create a list of integers in memory; it's a `range` object with a `__next__` method just like a file iterator.

Comment: @chepner thank you for clarifying that! :-) i don't know that much about python, it was just an idea^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the usage of the timeit module. When not specified, the param `number` defaults to 1e6. So what you are effectively measuring is how long it would take to append a hundred numbers to an array 1e6 times.

To verify this, I used this code snippet:

```
import timeit

alist = list(range(100))

L = []

def test():
    for i in alist:
        L.append(i)

elapsed = timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test, alist, L", number=1000000)

print('average time elapsed', elapsed/1000000)
```

On my machine, I got the following result:

```
7.74517...e-06
```

I do not know how you measured the append function for your txt file, but you could try to test it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use iPython, you can see a clearer explanation of the results using its `%timeit` magic command.

```
In [1]: def test():
   ...:     """Stupid test function"""
   ...:     L = []
   ...:     for i in range(100):
   ...:         L.append(i)
   ...:

In [2]: %timeit test()
7.12 µs ± 22.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Here the result is an average of 7.12 microseconds per call to `test`, with the average computed over 7 sets of 100,000 calls to `test`. This is consistent with the 7.75 microseconds reported by DocDriven in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243988/1126841).

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

def test():

L = []

for i in range(100)

```
    count + = i

    L.append(count )

    return count
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. But how is this an answer to the question? Also, please format your code correctly clicking the `edit` link, highlighting the code, then clicking the `{}` button (or press `Ctrl+K`).